# The project currently contains references to more than one version of Google.Apis

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Visual Studio 2010 (2012 does the same thing), new VB.Net project, Framework 4, added nuget packages for Google Calendar:

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Pre
```

Added Imports:

```
Imports Google.Apis
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Auth
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
```

This is my code to create the service and credentials:

```
Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)  

Dim service As CalendarService
Dim serviceAccountEmail As String = "ServiceAccountEmail@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
Dim certificate = New X509Certificate2("privatekey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

Dim credential As New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) With {
                                 .Scopes = scopes,
                                 .User = "myuser@there.com"
                                }.FromCertificate(certificate))

service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With
                                      {
                                          .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                                          .ApplicationName = "appName"
                                      })
```

I then got the "The project currently contains references to more than one version of Google.Apis, a direct reference to version 1.6.0.16897 and an indirect reference (through 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential') to version 1.6.0.27822. Change the direct reference to use version 1.6.0.27822 (or higher) of Google.Apis".

I get this if I try to use ServiceAccountCredential or UserCredential.

Had this problem a few weeks back, resolved it with using an older version of Google.Apis.Auth. But I had a hard time getting Service Accounts working (would just receive a warning:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException' occurred in Google.Apis.Auth.dll
```

and app would freeze).

So started from scratch to get the latest version and got this again, all Windows Updates done, last Nuget version (2.7), Am I the only one with this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't the only one.  I just got this fixed yesterday.  The server has new versions of Google.Apis.Auth but an old version of Google.Apis (hence the mismatch).  To fix, simply remove manually the "Google.Apis.Auth" and "Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices" from your references and then add in the version 1.6.0.16898 versions (found in the dotnet examples).

Problem Solved!

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes, that's how I got it fixed the first time I started my project. Got everything working with UserCredential, but wanted to have the ServiceAccountCredential working too, but couldn't (would not receive anything from the call: "Dim list As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items()".
App would just freeze.
Started over, thinking it could be something fixed in the later version, but still had the problem with version mismatch. I know it's still in pre-release, I'm just going to wait for ServiceAccountCredential in the next releases and see.